# error in the following sql server command

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2

```
select rf_id, bname 
from books 
where rf_id not in (select * 
                    from books 
                    where rf_id='" + tocheck + "');
```

When executed, it raised the following error. Please help me solve this error.

> Only one expression can be specified in the select list when the subquery is not introduced with EXISTS

Answer (score 1):

The `IN` operator is expecting to compare `rf_id` to a single column, so it should be:

```
where rf_id not in (select rf_id....
```

However, given that the subquery is being limited by `rf_id` anyway, you're better off just changing the query to be:

```
select rf_id, bname
from books
where rf_id <> '" + tocheck + "'
```

Answer (score 0):

USE:

```
select rf_id, bname 
from books 
where rf_id not in (select rf_id
                    from books 
                    where rf_id='" + tocheck + "')
```

Comment: In an aswer like this, it would be good to shortly explain, what you changed and why.

Comment: Also, is `**rf_id**` really valid syntax? If you meant to highlight it instead of it being literally like that, then use a comment in the code block, or explain it in words outside code block.

Comment: no, ** rf_id ** is not valid SQL syntax.Think @marc_s would only reformat to bold.